# Merging 2 partitioned tables BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to merge 2 partitioned tables in BigQuery:

- '**source_t**' is a source table. Its partitioned by Ingestion Time with Partition filter –

  `Required. Pseudo field _PARTITIONTIME is timestamp`
- '**target_t**' is a target table partitioned by field 'date' with Partition filter

  `Required. Field date is date`

I want to get data from last partition of **source** table and merge it to **target** table. To filter the search task on **tagret** table I need to use the field 'date' from the data of **source** table. I wrote a query but editor shows following query error:

> Cannot query over table 'MyDataSet.target_t' without a filter over column(s) 'date'

Here is my query:

```
declare latest default (select date(max(_PARTITIONTIME)) as latest from MyDataSet.source_t where _PARTITIONTIME >= timestamp(date_sub(current_date(),interval 1 day))); 
declare first_date default (select min(date) as first_date from MyDataSet.source_t where date(_PARTITIONTIME) = latest);
merge `MyDataSet.target_t` as a
using (select * from `MyDataSet.source_t` where _PARTITIONTIME = latest) as b 
on
  a.date >= first_date and
  a.date = b.date and
  a.account_id = b.account_id and 
  a.campaign_id = b.campaign_id and 
  a.adset_id = b.adset_id and 
  a.ad_id = b.ad_id 
when matched then update set 
  a.account_name = b.account_name, 
  a.campaign_name = b.campaign_name, 
  a.adset_name = b.adset_name, 
  a.ad_name = b.ad_name, 
  a.impressions = b.impressions, 
  a.clicks = b.clicks, 
  a.spend = b.spend, 
  a.date = b.date 
when not matched then insert row;
```

If I input date instead of 'latest' variable ("`where _PARTITIONTIME = '2020-10-01') as b`") there wont be any error. But I want to filter the source table properly.
And I don't get it how it affects the following 'on' statement and why everything brokes >.<
Could you please help? What is a proper syntax to write such query. And is there any other ways to run such merge without variables?

Answer (score 0):

> declare latest timestamp;

Your variable `latest` is a TIMESTAMP. Making it a DATE type then your query should work.

------ Update --------

The error is complaining about MyDataSet.target_t doesn't have a good filter on date column. Could you try put after `on` clause `a.date = latest` (if this is not the right filter, come up with other *constant* filter)

Comment: Thank you. I change the code to "declare latest default (select date(max(_PARTITIONTIME)) as latest from `MyDataSet.source_t`  where _PARTITIONTIME >= timestamp(date_sub(current_date(),interval 1 day)));
declare first_date default (select min(date) as first_date from `MyDataSet.source_t` where date(_PARTITIONTIME) = latest);
merge `MyDataSet.target_t` as a
using (select * from `MyDataSet.source_t` where date(_PARTITIONTIME) = latest) as b" but it still results in same error (

Comment: UPD: I tried another query with simple select and everything work just fine: "declare latest default (select max(_PARTITIONTIME) as latest from `MyDataSet.source_t` where _PARTITIONTIME >= timestamp(date_sub(current_date(),interval 1 day)));
declare first_date default (select min(date) as first_date from `MyDataSet.source_t` where _PARTITIONTIME = latest);
select * from `MyDataSet.target_t` where date >= first_date limit 100;"

Comment: Thank you again. It seems like the problem is because of Google couldn't predict what partitions to prune: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-partitioned-tables#pseudo_column_queries_that_scan_all_partitions

Comment: I think that cause of 2 variables Google don't get which dates should he use to prune partitions and he was going to search all partitions during search. I don't know if its an error of new functionality of scripting or compiler.